# Servo LIneSensor conflict

Tags: arduino

We are using a Prizm Genuino controller. We have been using a line sensor to successfully detect black lines but we seem to be getting a conflict with our servos now.  The lineSensor does not seem to be giving us a reading.  We think this has also happened with our ultraSonic sensor. Hoping someone can point us in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics:SE.  Without knowing more about your code, exactly what hardware you are using, and how you have connected all the elements, I'm not sure anyone will be able to offer any meaningful suggestions.  Please edit your question to include that information.  You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: you have provided near zero information .... only a guess can be made ..... replace the sensor